# Multiply textboxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have used a jsFiddle that I found on another question on here that will work perfectly if I can get the subtotal to multiply instead of addition.

I am sure this is a really easy fix, but I'm struggling to make the change.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/77uxK/48/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    function calcSum(prevVal){
        sum = sum - prevVal + (this.value/1);
        return sum;
    }
    var subAmt = $("#sub"), taxAmt = $("#tax"), totAmt = $("#total");
    $(".val").each(function(){
        var prevVal = this.value/1, self = this;
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            subAmt.val(calcSum.call(self, prevVal));
            totAmt.val(sum + sum*parseFloat(taxAmt.val()/100));
            prevVal = self.value;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: which is the line where you want to multiply

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, the subtotal line, the total line should then calucate the tax

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.  If you had so much as glanced at the description of the tags you were slapping on this question, that difference might have become apparent..

Comment: Andrew, I originally did post it as Javascipt only, but I received  an error saying I didn't have high enough reputation. Please do accepet my apologises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change the function to

```
function calcSum(prevVal) {
    var val1 = $('#val1').val();
    var val2 = $('#val2').val();
    sum = parseInt(val1) * parseInt(val2); // parseFloat based on your need change it
    return sum;
}
```

**[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/77uxK/70/)**

Comment: Hi Soul, I copied this code into the jsFiddle and it didn't seem to work

Comment: just enter values in the value1 and value2 and click on the jsfiddle link given above @padders01

Comment: do you know how to make the total only show 2 decimal places?

Comment: @padders01 the output is it nor the subtotal user `.toFixed(2)`

Comment: Ok I will try that. I have noticed if I put decimals into the value boxes then it calculates wrongly. For example try 2.5 in both boxes. It returns a sub total of 6.25

Comment: use parseFloat  @padders01

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/77uxK/81/                       ` totAmt.val(sum + sum*parseFloat(taxAmt.val()/100));`
            `  totAmt.val() .toFixed(1);`